# Calling a method with an index on ArrayList in c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, arraylist

Ok here is my dilemma, I want to create an array of custom objects but then be able to do something like `list[index].method` call.

as an example:

- program starts
- program creates a master array which holds `GenericClass< T >(param)`
- each generic class then creates an array of type `T`

I can get that part to work ok but then when I try to use my object methods such as

```
object[] MasterList = new object[MASTER_LIST_SIZE]; 
// add contents to MasterList

MasterList[index].setValueAt(MethodIndex, value);
```

I get a message that reads object has no method named setValueAt which requires one parameter(s)

I will admit that what I am trying to do is rather dumb and I could probably do it easier with reading a text file or something but if there is a way to do it like this I would like to know how or at least what I am missing.

Comment: Why do you get a "no method named setValueAt which requires one parameter" error when you are actually passing two arguments?

Comment: What is the static type of MasterList?

Comment: @Everett - I'm gonna take a wild guess and say you are using `ArrayList`?

Comment: object[]  MasterList = new object[MASTER_LIST_SIZE];

Comment: @Everett - If you know the type of the contents of the array why are you not taking advantage of that fact?

Comment: @ChaosPandion if you are referring to something like myClassName< T >[] = new myClassName< T >; it is the < T > part that messes things up and quite frankly I don't understand how to make the generics work in this situation

Comment: @Everett - C# generics can be your best friend if you take the time to truly understand how they work.

Comment: @ChaosPandion that's the idea :) that is why I wanted to do it this way   take what I don't understand and play with it until I know it better than I know myself :) when I get stuck ans those in the know

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of unknowns about what you are doing but my best guess is that you need to cast the result to the type you need.

```
((GenericClass<T>)MasterList[index]).setValueAt(MethodIndex, value);
```

Comment: that got me close enough that I think I can work with it  thanks :)